# How does an OS decide value of TTL in an outgoing ICMP packet

Tags: ping, ipv4, ttl

I noticed that when I ping different sites, the outgoing ICMP has varying TTL values for example:

```
ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=116
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=116
```

whereas

```
ping 1.1.1.1

Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=52
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=89ms TTL=52
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=87ms TTL=52
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=52
```

So, how does the OS decide that for 8.8.8.8 it is good to set high TTL whereas for 1.1.1.1 a lower TTL is fine?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited on a different Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 1):

The TTL is determined by the remote host. The ping you see in the shell is the echo response. The initial TTL is set by the OS. Linux uses 64, Windows 128 and Routers 255. Every Hop reduces the TTL by at least 1.

For example: If you ping an Linux Host and there are 12 Hops between, than the TTL is 64-12 = 52.

Comment: Thanks. Looks logical.